# how to create a long format table from multiple columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-area-chart, proportions, long-format-data

I would like to know, how can I do long format table.

[this is what I have:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68eUF.png)

[and this is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSfVl.png)

if you are asking what I would like to do, it is for ggplot2 proportional stacked area chart.
thank you very much

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+how+to+create+a+long+format+table+from+multiple+columns ... Posting a question with only links to pictures of data and apparently not having done any searching is not a great way to make your first SO posting. I suggest you delete this question which will undoubtedly attract lots of downvotes and read the [help] pages and learn how to [ask]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try:

library(tidyverse)

your_dataframe%>%
pivot_longer(-Date, names_to = "plylum", values_to = "percent")

Comment: thank you very much. I am new in rstudio and I never done it before, so im learning.